# Where can I find libdvdread?

Tags: dvd

I'm trying to install Bombono the DVD editing tool, and the readme tells me to build it with scons, only scons stops me with this warning:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Creating new config file: config.opts
Checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler ... yes
Checking whether we are using the Clang compiler ... no
Checking for pkg-config ... yes
Checking for C header file sys/types.h... yes
Checking for C header file sys/stat.h... yes
Checking for C header file stdlib.h... yes
Checking for C header file string.h... yes
Checking for C header file memory.h... yes
Checking for C header file strings.h... yes
Checking for C header file inttypes.h... yes
Checking for C header file stdint.h... yes
Checking for C header file unistd.h... yes
Checking for C header file dlfcn.h... yes
Checking for C header file sys/timeb.h... yes
Checking for C header file sys/time.h... yes
Checking for C header file time.h... yes
Checking for C header file io.h... no
Checking for struct timeval ... yes
Checking for C function ftime()... yes
Checking for C function gettimeofday()... yes
Checking maximum supported data alignment ... no
Checking whether compiler understands __builtin_expect ... yes
Checking return type of signal handlers ... void
Checking for inline ... yes ('inline')
Checking for restrict ... yes ('restrict')
Checking for DVDOpenFile() in C library dvdread... no

****************************************************
Can't find library libdvdread!
****************************************************
```

Researched the problem a bit and tried several downloads, one of them being updating gstreamer but it seems like the solutions are outdated

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/libdvdread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal method to do this is

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdvdread-dev
```

---

Works on 16.04.

Comment: works thanks, but now im finding there are several other dependencies that are missing for this to work...it would be easy if i could just download them all at once

Comment: copy paste them into an `apt-get install` is the easiest ;)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found it on Videolan website.. https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/libdvdread/